# Getting any element in array matching with statement

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to loop over array to get all elements and process if any elements matches condition of array. They execute.

```
def alarm():
    for i in timetable:
        i_time = i
        i_minute = i.minute
        while True:
            if i_hour == dt.datetime.now().hour and i_minute == dt.datetime.now().minute:
                #playsound('media/ClassAlarm.mp3')
                print("Its time")
                break
```

Issue it keeps waiting for `t1` then proceeds to `t2` which doesn't happen due to condition.
I have tried to put whole array in as `time[] == datetime.datetime.now().time` which doesn't work as as well. It returns with invalid syntax error. How can I get second or any index element to follow the condition

Comment: If you are trying to see if 2 is in the array you can just do `2 in array`

Comment: Not specific to 2. Any element should be satisfying condition. No going through sequence like it is going now

Comment: so what value are you looking for?

Comment: Any value which matches the if statement.. Not specific to me. example if condition is true with second element then it should ignore 1 st element and go to second and so on.

Comment: Yes I am asking what the condition is

Comment: I have updated question you can check properly.

Comment: what do you mean it is waiting?

Comment: So t1 is a time that has passed it is waiting for t1 and t2 is about to happen. It should go to t2 if t1 doesn't execute.. But it is waiting t1 to happen which gonna be next day... So no matter when programme is executed it should work properly

Comment: there is no code here for waiting. also I don't think you know what execute means. I'm voting to close this question as it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: I do know what execute means. I will try explaining again. so t1 is 5:54 and t2 is 5:58. Current time is 5:56. I want a certain things to happen if any of time t1 or t2 is met with current time.. Lets say alarm as example. So if its past 5:54 already it should go to next element t2.. But code is waiting for 5:54 to happen again which will be tomorrow.

Comment: How is the code waiting this is a simple for loop and if statement

Comment: Yes. I don't understand myself. It keeps waiting for t1 to be true only then it goes to t2. Tried debugging many ways. But if t1 is above current time it executes properly. wait for t2 to happen and then exit.. but if t1 is already passed it doesn't work and keep waiting

Comment: If your code is waiting then there is more code you aren't showing us

Comment: I added more code.. Customised it according to example of alarm

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Ok i don't know if i understand correctly but maybe smth like

```
array = [t1, t2]
for elt in array:
  time = datetime.datetime.now()
  if time < elt:
    break
  while(True):    
    if time == elt:
      print("you did it")
```

EDIT2:
one more try

Comment: It didn't execute 2nd element and still waiting for 1st element to appear. This doesn't work.

Comment: @SahilM It doesn't work because you did a poor job of explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is still not working.. As code is waiting for t1

Comment: I am pretty sure this code checks for both t1 and t2 but maybe i don't understand actual use case

Comment: Yes. It does checks for t1 and t2. Use case is that if t1 is passed then go to t2. I tried explaining in detail with example in above comment. one way would be using if statements for both. But there are multiple cases which will create many if statements. I do not want to create that way.

Comment: It says unsupported operand for datetime.time and datetime.time. You cannot subtract datetime.time from datetime.time

Comment: maybe try time < elt just google comparing dates, i don't remember what is the proper way to do it

Comment: I have tried Comparing already.. it isn't helping.. I found any() function.. But I am not able to use it efficiently yet. Maybe I will have solution there